# How to send an object and array through Angularjs service

Tags: angularjs, rest, api

I am trying to send an object and array in the same time to an API, but i got an error

This is the object (from input boxes)

```
 var vacation = {
            Vac_Main_Key: $scope.vackey, Vac_Main_Code: $scope.code, Gender_Type: $scope.gen, CareeService_Flag: $scope.career, Vac_Duration: $scope.vduration,
            Duration_Flag: $scope.vflag}
```

This is the array (from multiple check boxes)

```
 $scope.selectedcontract = function (con)
    {
        if (con.details == true) {
            $scope.vacationcontracts.push({ VacMKey: $scope.vackey, WType: con.sys_key });
            console.log($scope.vacationcontracts);
        }
        else if (con.details == false) {
            $scope.vacationcontracts.splice(con, 1);
        }

    }
```

The save button

```
var promisePost = vacationsetupSrv.save(vacation, $scope.vacationcontracts);
        promisePost.then(function () {}
```

The angularjs service:

```
var vacationsetup = angular.module("vacationsetup", [])
                        .service("vacationsetupSrv", function ($http) {

                            var urlBase = "/VacationSetupAPI/api";



                            this.save = function (url, vacation,vacationcontracts) {
                                return $http({
                                    method: "POST",
                                    url: urlBase + '/' + url,
                                    data: vacation, vacationcontracts,
                                    async: false,
                                })

                            };
```

i got this error `http://localhost/VacationSetupAPI/api/[object%20Object]`
Any help, Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is so wrong, your first parameter should not be an object `vacationsetupSrv.save(vacation, $scope.vacationcontracts);` you're putting the object in the first parameter that is why you're requesting a wrong endpoint, and one thing what is the exact payload of your api?

Comment: i replaced the scope,  var promisePost = vacationsetupSrv.save($scope.vacationcontracts,vacation); but i got this error http://localhost/VacationSetupAPI/api/[object%20Object],[object%20Object] , what do you mean by payload? Thanks

Comment: **payload** the data that you want to send to your server, look at your `vacationsetupSrv -> this.save`, you have 3 parameters, what should be the value of `url`?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.save = function (vacation,vacationcontracts) {
```

You are sending *object* as 1st argument and then assigning it to the **url** as string, that’s wrong.

```
vacationsetupSrv.save(vacation, $scope.vacationcontracts);
```

**OR**

Try

```
vacationsetupSrv.save(“”,vacation, $scope.vacationcontracts);
```